# ARIA role for SVG that contains links

Tags: html, svg, accessibility, wai-aria

I have an inline SVG of a world map. Some of the countries are highlighted and clickable. In order to make the map as accessible as possible, I've added an ARIA role and `aria-labelledby` attribute linking the SVG to its description:

```html
<svg role="img" aria-labelledby="description">

  <!-- description -->
  <desc id="description">A world map illustration. The following two countries are highlighted: United States, United Kingdom.</desc>

  <!-- countries -->
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path data-name="United States" class="country highlighted" d="..." />
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path data-name="United Kingdom" class="country highlighted" d="..." />
  </a>
  <path data-name="Canada" class="country" d="..." />
  <path data-name="Mexico" class="country" d="..." />
  ...

</svg>
```

However, I'm worried that many assistive technologies will stop at the image element and not continue traversing down the tree, preventing users from interacting with the links inside.

Inspecting the element with Chrome devtools and looking at the [Accessibility Tree](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/accessibility/reference#tree) seems to confirm this suspicion. When I focus the `<a>` element, it comes up as `Ignored` in the Accessibility Tree pane.

**The question:** What is the correct way to mark up this SVG so that it is appropriately labeled and the constituent links are clickable, and (ideally) it keep its semantics as an image?

Should I be using multiple `role` values? Or is adding the `img` role more hurtful than helpful in this instance? Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution that seems to be working:

There is a newer value for the `role` attribute, [`figure`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#figure), that has the semantics of a graphic while allowing its contents to remain accessible:

> `figure` **(role)**
>
> A perceivable [`section`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#section) of content that typically contains a [graphical document](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#dfn-graphical-document), images, code snippets, or example text. The parts of a `figure` ***MAY*** be user-navigable.

So `role="img"` on the SVG in the example should be changed to `role="figure"`.